# How do I set the form that loads on startup of my Windows Forms application in VS2010? (Setting startup object to no avail)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've read up on this and I'm ready to punt at this point.

I'm working on a C# project in VS2010. Within the solution I'm working with, I have two class files/ dll's, and a windows forms project called "TradingApp". The forms project has one form, a main form. There is also a form in one of the class files. I want the main form in TradingApp to be the startup form. I have set the startup project in the solution to my app, and have set the TradingApp startup object to "TradingApp.Program." I also call my form by name as so: `Application.Run(new frmTradingAppMain());` from Main(). (I didn't see my form name as an option). When I run the program, it appears that a blank version of the *other* form in my class library is loading.

I'm at my wits end, and your mercy. Thanks in advance...

Kevin

Here's main as requested:

```
static void Main()
{
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
  Application.Run(new frmTradingAppMain());
}
```

Update: Of course it had to be something on the nose... I (somehow) was missing:

```
public frmTradingAppMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Can you post Main function here?

Comment: Your `frmTradingAppMain` form doesn't load the other form and hide itself, by any chance? A form in a class library can't load itself, and an assembly can't be set as a startup object if the relevent entry point isn't defined. Also, what does the debugger say is happening?

Comment: Sure, it's below. Btw, it only looks as though it's the other form... it's blank, and the other form has controls. The size is the same however.

Comment: Check for an OnLoad() override or frmTradingAppMain_Load() method in frmTradingAppMain, maybe you're opening the other form there. Check the constructor too. Also show us your Program.Main().

Comment: Try putting debug breakers on both forms and see who is calling it.

Comment: You guys are crazy fast! :) Thanks. I have to head to calc, I thought I'd post and see a suggestion or two after class. So I'll be going through suggestions later tonight. I hope threads here stay active and current for a bit. Thanks again.

Comment: @LarsTech OK... so I put a breakpoint in each forms' partial class, on the respective default constructor. Neither gets hit! I click run on my main form, the small blank form appears, without entering debug mode.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: The form did instantiate an instance of one of my types, that contains an instance of the smaller, "other" form. I commented this out though, and the problem persists.

Comment: If a "blank version" of the form is showing - search your entire solution for the phrase `class frmTradingAppMain`. You may have two declarations for the class (in different namespaces).

Answer (score 3):

Please go to `Program.cs` and change the form name in `Application.run()` to the name which you want to be the startup.

For example:

```
Application.Run(new MyForm());
```

Answer (score 1):

> (I didn't see my form name as an option)

From this statement, I have to wonder if you are including or calling your form with the correct namespace for it. It sounds to me like Main() is in a different namespace than the form (frmTradingAppMain) that you are wanting to show. Check the frmTradingAppMain cs file for the namespace and try adding that before the formname.

So for example, if your form is in the namespace TradingApp, the frmTradingAppMain.cs file might start something like this:

```
namespace TradingApp
{
   public partial class frmTradingAppMain
   { 
      ...
   }
}
```

So then from main, you would try to start it like this:

```
 static void Main()
 {
   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
   Application.Run(new TradingApp.frmTradingAppMain());
 }
```

Comment: thanks, maybe there's something I'm not seeing here... Main() is in a static class "Program", in the TradingApp namespace, in a Program.cs file. My TradingApp.cs file has two namespaces in it, in which I have various class definitions. My frmTradingAppMain form is in the TradingApp namespace, in its respective file. I'm sure it's on the nose obvious! Any more takers? Thanks again...